# R is not able to find shared library

Tags: r, shared-libraries

I need to load an Rcpp package which has linked against the libprotobuf.so. I manually installed the library into a certain directory and added this directory to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If I list the content of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then I find the library. If I execute:

```
system("ldd /correct/path/to/lib/MyRPackage.so")
```

then I see that the protobuf library is successfully found. But if the MyRPackage is called the first time, I get:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
 unable to load shared object '/correct/path/to/lib/MyRPackage.so':
 libprotobuf.so.3.15.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The library is only found correctly (and therefore the code executes correctly) if I explicitly load it via

```
dyn.load("full/path/libprotobuf.so.3.15.8.0")
```

But I don't want to specify all libraries which are needed in the code. Why does dyn.load() not search in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH? In my understanding, if MyRPackage.so is loaded, the linked libraries are searched for in the usual places like /usr/lib or LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Can you please expand the question and explain why you would need a manual `dyn.load()`?   Otherwise the `RProtoBuf` package shows you how (reliably) build a package using Protocol Buffers. (Also, `dyn.load()` is _not_ generic shared library linker but used only internally by R to load shared libraries _for its extension packages_,)

Comment: This is more or less my question. I don't understand why I need to manually call dyn.load() and I also don't want to do it. If I use my package the first time, then I get the above error message. It seems that R is not automatically searching the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when loading the MyRPackage.so. This is not only about protobuf. I also need other shared libraries.

Comment: I think the short answer is that R will work just like the rest of the system and use ldd to resolve shared libraries _that are external dependencies of a package_. That is how RProtoBuf resolves to (on my system currently) libprotobuf.so.23 and friends.  But it matters _how_ you build your package, and the process is described in _Writing R Extensions_. I also add a little in the newer vignette [R libraries](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-libraries.pdf) -- maybe you can take a read?

Comment: I had a quick look and I will read through it more carefully. I just used PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) -L/path/to/my/libraries/ -lprotobuf to link the library. The package compiles fine and also runs on other systems. If you say, R will just use ldd to resolve the shared library, then I don't understand why the system("ldd ...") call can resolve the library one single line before a MyRPackage::my_function() call crashes it with the above error.

Comment: I think it might help your understanding of these matters if you spent some time with i) [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) (also came with your copy of R), ii) the aforementioned Rcpp vignette on 'how to build with external libraries) (also on arXiv) and iii) if you studied some (simpler?) packages with external libraries -- some graphics and file formats have good ones.

Comment: And I think we should remove the `[rcpp]` tag here.  The question has nothing to do with Rcpp, it is really about R, compiled extension packages and external dependencies.  Which is a large topic, but somewhat orthogonal to whether or not you use Rcpp to help with data conversion and "glue". [Done.]

Answer (score -1):

Try running the ldconfig command. R probably uses the dlfcn library to dynamically load other libraries and according to [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-889363/) dlfcn can sometimes get confused and need to find it in /etc/ld.so.cache.

Comment: No, I don't think this is an applicable answer.